# Should I invest 50% of my savings (20K) into a family business?

Tags: risk, risk-management

Somebody in my family is proposing an investment opportunity.

The deal is as follows.
You put 20K and he is going to use it to sow rice, the return depends on the price per kg of rice but he tells me that the average ROI is about 15% in 4 months.  I guess some risks are bad wheater, or something bad happening to the rice, etc. He is just starting with this business this month.

I have 40K on a savings account. I don't have any car or credit card payments. My income is 70K/year as a Software Developer. I'm 25 single.

My question is, should I invest 20K in this medium-risk business? I want to keep it compounding over several years. I am afraid that the lack of knowledge in that industry would play against me.

Comment: How much experience does your family member have growing rice?

Comment: You'll get your 20K plus an extra 1500 back in four months?

Comment: I'd be highly dubious of any investment that averaged a 15% return in 4 months.  That would be a roughly 75% annual gain which is not consistent with the idea that this is a "medium-risk business".  That's very much in the realm of the "too good to be true" returns that are the hallmark of a scam.  If you could make that sort of return growing rice, something that tens of millions of people do every year and that they have been doing for thousands of years, rice farmers would dominate the Forbes list of richest people.

Comment: @RonJohn he has some experience (but less than a year) and has done relatively small investments, it has given him good results.

Comment: @RonJohn and yes, it would be like 23K return after the harvest which is 4 months long

Comment: "and has done relatively small investments" in growing rice?

Comment: The important questions to ask yourself are, (1) "how would I be *financially* affected if I lost all that money due to a bad harvest?" and (2) "how would *family* relations be affected if he is lazy or incompetent or is scamming you?"

Comment: Also, will you get to see the books?  If you're ponying up all the cash, you should have the right to go over them, to verify that he's not wasting it.

Comment: @JustinCave How do you get 75%? Even if rice can be grown year-round (which is not generally the case), 1.15^(12/4) = 1.52, so 52% at most.

Comment: @RonJohn 15% of 20K is 3000, not 1500, right?

Comment: @nanoman grrr... I did the math (to ensure I didn't make a math error), and then took the "15" from 15%.  :(

Comment: "Somebody in my family is proposing an investment opportunity" ... No. I didn't need to read past the first sentence.

Comment: 15% in 4 months is 52% per year. (1.15 raised to the power of 3). This seems high for a commodity business. Perhaps this rate is being calculated without all costs. For example is there any free labor and free management or free use of land. What happens if "free" resources turn into resentment?

Comment: @H2ONaCl Most crops are seasonal, rice is typically planted in spring and harvested in fall. Likely the return from one growing season is your annual return.

Comment: @nanoman - Because I'm an idiot.  I took 1.15^(12/3) because I mixed up in my head "4 months" and "3 periods".

Comment: Guys, all that needs to be said here is **IT'S A SCAM**.   I suggest, it just complicates matters making jokes, obtuse comments etc

Comment: @JustinCave as I was reading your long comment I enjoyed it more and more - and the final sentence made me break out in laughter  :)  cheers ...

Comment: "Should I ..." questions are not preferred here. If you can [edit] this into a "What criteria can I use to make a decision?" type of question, it would be valid.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are not familiar with rice farming, you should ask your relative more questions and do some research to check if the numbers are reasonable.

You want to understand the business plan. In particular: What exactly is the 20K to be spent on? Whose land and labor are being used and how are they valued/compensated? What does your relative get out of the deal?

If you decide to proceed, make a written contract so the terms are clear.

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't. Reasons are:

- A 15% ROI in 4 months is likely either simply a wrong guess by your relative, willful deceit or attached with significant, unspoken of risk. This turns your investment into gambling. You should not gamble with 50% of your networth, even if you might be able to replace it comparably quickly with your current salary.
- Don't mix family and investments. What happens if you won't get the expected return? What if you don't get anything back? Will there be resentment? Will you sue (if you have a contract)? This might lead to uncomfortable family gatherings in the future and might force other members of your family to pick sides.
- You lack knowledge in the industry (and so does he if he is just starting this month). Don't invest in something you don't understand sufficiently. If the investment unexpectedly does work out well for you, you might mistakenly assume it's because of your skills rather than sheer luck, potentially leading to further bad decisions in the future.
- If it would be a great decision, the person should be able to acquire 20k on their own from a bank. If they cannot get 20k from a bank in the current environment, you should second guess their business acumen as reflected in their personal finances.

If you still decide to do it, do get a contract as pointed out by nanoman.

Comment: "Family" is quite often the source of initial business capital.

Comment: @RonJohn Money is also quite often the source of decade long conflicts within families. If you cannot acquire sufficient funds to finance a business but must rely on family, it's in my opinion too risky an investment for it to compound over several years. Now if we talk about gifting the money to family (or the equivalent of gifting given the risks) with no expectations on return, it's of course a different matter. I would still advice against gifting 50% of your networth to anyone unless they are in dire straits.

Comment: Yup, **it can**.  And also, **it can** be a great source of seed money.

Comment: For goodness sake.  It is a risible scam.  No point confusing the issue with abstractions.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's a complete, total, scam<sup>†</sup>
2. If you truly want to try something like this, **try a small amount**.  Based on your outstanding financial condition as described, you could try $1,000.  If the system is so fantastic, you'll make money on that.  ***ABSOLUTELY DO NOT PUT IN MORE THAN $1,000. IF THE MINIMUM IS HIGHER THAN THAT FORGET IT.***
3. Here's what you say when someone wants $20,000 from you:

> Jack, that's a fantastic idea. Let's do this. You grab your credit card, and buy $20,000 of the stuff.  Let's review your results after the three months.  The profit will easily cover your small interest charges on the card. Let's get started!  I'm more than happy to help by driving the truck or whatever is needed. Once we've tested that it works a couple times with your credit card, I may invest too.

---

<sup>†</sup>  I have no idea "who" the scam is enacted by, it could be anyone up and down the line. Your Family Member who is suggesting the idea could well be being scammed.

Comment: Last sentence of the answer is critical - if the uncle hasn't actually gone it yet, and relations between OP and the uncle are 'good enough', it might even be worthwhile to raise the subject with him to say "hey, are you sure these results you're hoping for aren't too good to be true?"